# Regular expressions in PostgreSQL version 8.3

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am having problems matching a pattern from log files I am analyzing on a Postgres 8.3 instance.

The patterns I am trying to match are

```
cs(User-Agent)=-

cs(Referer)=-
```

I have tried both the `like` and the `~` operator with the escapes below but no luck so far:

```
select * from database
where ~ E'\(Referer\)\=\-';

select * from database
where like 'cs\(User\-Agent\=\-)';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the [psql] tag is for the command line interface `psql` - look at tag description! You mean PostgreSQL. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE [field name here] LIKE '%cs(User-Agent%'
```

Notice the choice of a column from which the data you are analyzing is drawn, and the percent signs (wildcards), indicating that you want to find the string anywhere in the field.  Without the wildcards, you won't match anything.